# RabbitMQ Consumer performance issue

Tags: performance, rabbitmq, consumer

We have used: 'Work Queues'/Direct(using name identification, i.e. https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html) for production environment.

Here, problem that we are facing is that Server is able to send required messages to RabbitMQ. However, client is **NOT** able to read message from RabbitMQ efficiently. We identified by putting required details when particular message is read by consumer.

Can anyone have faced such kind of issue? Please suggest.

Note: When I have checked 'Overview' tab of RabbitMQ, found that 13GB are left in local disk where RabbitMQ is running and 13GB is already used by RabbitMQ. I am not sure this can result into any issue!! It is like as below:

Disk space: Used: 13GB
            Limit: 48MB

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know if disk is  a problem or not. To inform you, I want to share my rabbitmq server statistics. I have 4.1 GB space on disk and when I check my rabbitmq node, 4.1 GB Free and 48 MB Limit is seen. So if it says 13GB used than disk space may be the problem. By the way my RabbitMQ version 3.5.1 and I have no performance issues.

Comment: What is exact problem? Can't get it from your question, re-read it multiple time, sorry.

Comment: In addition, to help you help you may your software and hardware configuration, environment and specify how do you load your server. What is your RabbitMQ metrics shown in admin panel? Does server/cluster run into flow control state? As of written, it is hard to guess what is exact problem. For me, this looks like more a  seeking for debugging help question. If it so, probably, you may find [rabbitmq-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users) (official RabbitMQ user group) more suitable.

Comment: Thank you for reply. we are using RabbitMQ 3.2.3. Here, problem is that for example producer is able to send messages to RabbitMQ at **01:48:39.280**. But consumer is reading message at **01:51:09.817** which is taking too much time. I am diagnosing on this.